# List data is not showing on Datagrid + MVVM what I am doing wrong?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

DataAccess:

This is a dataaccess class where I have created a list item

```
namespace MVVMTest2.DataAccess
{
    class DataAccessClass
    {
        readonly List<EmployeeList> _employeeList;

         public DataAccessClass()
         {
             if (_employeeList == null)
             {
                _employeeList = new List<EmployeeList>();
             }
             _employeeList.Add(EmployeeList.CreateEmployee("MD", "Mishu", "M", "72000"));
             //_employeeList.Add(EmployeeList.CreateEmployee("MD", "Mou", "F", "82000"));
             //_employeeList.Add(EmployeeList.CreateEmployee("Jill", "Jack", "M", "92000"));
             //_employeeList.Add(EmployeeList.CreateEmployee("John", "Smith", "M", "85000"));
             //_employeeList.Add(EmployeeList.CreateEmployee("Amanda", "Scholl", "F", "49000"));

        }

        //public List<EmployeeList> GetEmployeeInfo()

        public ObservableCollection<EmployeeList> GetEmployeeInfo()
        {
            // return new List<EmployeeList>(_employeeList);

            return new ObservableCollection<EmployeeList>(_employeeList);
        }

    }

    internal class EmployeeList
    {
        string FirstName;
        string LastName;
        string Gender;
        string Salary;

        public static EmployeeList CreateEmployee(string firstName, string lastname, string gender, string salary)
        {
            return new EmployeeList { FirstName = firstName, LastName = lastname, Gender = gender, Salary = salary };
        }
    }
}
```

Model Class:

```
namespace MVVMTest2.Model
{
    class ModelClass
    {
        private string _model;

        private DataAccessClass _data;

        public ModelClass()
        {
        }

        //public List<EmployeeList> GetDataSet()
        public ObservableCollection<EmployeeList> GetDataSet()
        {
            /*
            List<string> cities = new List<string>();
            cities.Add("New York");
            cities.Add("Mumbai");
            cities.Add("Berlin");
            cities.Add("Istanbul");

            // Join strings into one CSV line.
            string line = string.Join("\n", cities.ToArray());
            */

            ObservableCollection<EmployeeList> list = new ObservableCollection<EmployeeList>();
            DataAccessClass daC = new DataAccessClass();
            list = daC.GetEmployeeInfo();
            //string line = string.Join("\n", list.ToArray());

            return list;
        }


        public string GetDataList()
        {
            List<string> cities = new List<string>();
            cities.Add("New York");
            cities.Add("Mumbai");
            cities.Add("Berlin");
            cities.Add("Istanbul");

            // Join strings into one CSV line.
            string line = string.Join("\n", cities.ToArray());
            return line;
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel :

```
namespace MVVMTest2.ViewModel
{
    class ViewModelAll : ViewModelBase,INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ModelClass _model;

        public ViewModelAll()
        {
            _canExecute = true;
            _model = new ModelClass();
        }

        private string _firstName;

        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return _firstName; }
            set { _firstName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
            }
        }

        private string _lastName;

        public string LastName
        {
            get { return _lastName; }
            set
            {
                _lastName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("LastName");
            }
        }

        //private List<EmployeeList> _displayName;
        private ObservableCollection<EmployeeList> _displayName = new ObservableCollection<EmployeeList>();
        public ObservableCollection<EmployeeList> DisplayText
        {
            get { return _displayName; }
            set
            {
                _displayName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DisplayText");
            }
        }

        //private List<EmployeeList> _dataGrid;
        //public List<EmployeeList> DataSet
        private ObservableCollection<EmployeeList> _dataGrid = new ObservableCollection<EmployeeList>();
        public ObservableCollection<EmployeeList> DataSet
        {
            get { return _dataGrid; }
            set
            {
                _dataGrid = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DataSet");
            }
        }

        private List<EmployeeList> _dataList;
        public List<EmployeeList> DataList
        {
            get { return _dataList; }
            set
            {
                _dataList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DataList");
            }
        }

        private bool _canExecute;

        private ICommand _submitCommand;

        public ICommand SubmitCommand
        {
            get { return _submitCommand ?? (_submitCommand = new CommandHandler(() => MyAction(), _canExecute));}
        }

        private ICommand _closeCommand;

        public ICommand CloseCommand
        {
            get { return _closeCommand ?? (_closeCommand = new CommandHandler(() => MyClose(), _canExecute)); }
        }

        private void MyClose()
        {
            Application.Current.MainWindow.Close();
        }

        public void MyAction()
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("you are here");
            //FirstName = string.Empty;
            //OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
            List<string> kala = new List<string>();
            //var getdata = _model.GetDataList();
            var getdata = _model.GetDataSet();
            //var getcity = _model.GetDataList();
            DisplayText = getdata;
            // DataList =getdata;
            DataSet = getdata;
            //OnPropertyChanged("DataSet");
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource ="{Binding DataSet}" Name="dataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,158,0,0" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="70" Width="480" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="FirstName" Binding="{Binding FirstName}" Width="120"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="LastName" Binding="{Binding LastName}" Width="120" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Gender" Binding="{Binding Gender}" Width="120"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Salary" Binding="{Binding Salary}" Width="*"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, there is no need to have an `ObservableCollection` in your `ViewModel`, `Model`, and `DataAccess`. `ObservableCollections` are used for binding (mainly) of collections that you want to monitor the adding/removing of elements. They are typically used within the `ViewModel` and/or the `Model` only.

With that said, you can just simply have an `ObservableCollection` within your `ViewModelAll` class.

Second, you do not need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for properties that will not change its data source. You can remove that from your `ViewModelAll` class as well.

Lastly, your `XAML` is bound to `EmployeeList` properties, yet you have them defined ad member variables only. ***In order to make binding work, they must be properties (with a getter and setter)***.

I've refactored your code a bit just to get the `DataGrid` binding to work (and have simplified it). Take a look, and let me know if you have any questions.

**ViewModelAll.cs**

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    class ViewModelAll : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ModelClass _model;

        public ObservableCollection<EmployeeList> DataSet
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public ViewModelAll()
        {
            _model = new ModelClass();
            DataSet = new ObservableCollection<EmployeeList>();

            MyAction();
        }


        private void MyClose()
        {
            Application.Current.MainWindow.Close();
        }

        public void MyAction()
        {
            foreach (var datum in _model.GetDataSet())
            {
                DataSet.Add(datum);
            }
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (PropertyChanged == null) return;

            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
        #endregion INotifyPropertyChanged
    }
}
```

**DataAccessClass.cs**

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    class DataAccessClass
    {
        readonly List<EmployeeList> _employeeList;

        public DataAccessClass()
        {
            if (_employeeList == null)
            {
                _employeeList = new List<EmployeeList>();
            }

            _employeeList.Add(EmployeeList.CreateEmployee("MD", "Mishu", "M", "72000"));
            _employeeList.Add(EmployeeList.CreateEmployee("MD", "Mou", "F", "82000"));
            _employeeList.Add(EmployeeList.CreateEmployee("Jill", "Jack", "M", "92000"));
            _employeeList.Add(EmployeeList.CreateEmployee("John", "Smith", "M", "85000"));
            _employeeList.Add(EmployeeList.CreateEmployee("Amanda", "Scholl", "F", "49000"));

        }

        public List<EmployeeList> GetEmployeeInfo()
        {
            return new List<EmployeeList>(_employeeList);
        }
    }

    internal class EmployeeList
    {
        public string FirstName { get; private set; }
        public string LastName { get; private set; }
        public string Gender { get; private set; }
        public string Salary { get; private set; }

        public static EmployeeList CreateEmployee(string firstName, string lastname, string gender, string salary)
        {
            return new EmployeeList { FirstName = firstName, LastName = lastname, Gender = gender, Salary = salary };
        }
    }
}
```

**ModelClass.cs**

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    class ModelClass
    {
        private DataAccessClass _data;
        public ModelClass()
        {
            _data = new DataAccessClass();
        }
        public List<EmployeeList> GetDataSet()
        {
            return _data.GetEmployeeInfo();
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.Xaml.cs**

Make sure you don't forget to set the DataContext.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new ViewModelAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide me the ViewModelall.cs. Unfortunately, you have posted same code as DataAccessClass

Comment: @MisuZAMAN see update. sorry about that, copy/paste error